# BIML Visual studio validation error

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, bids, biml

```html
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="Varigence.Biml.CoreLowerer.SchemaManagement" #>
    <# var connection = SchemaManager.CreateConnectionNode("SchemaProvider", "Data Source=servername\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SSISIncrementalLoad_Source;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;"); #>
    <# var tables = connection.GenerateTableNodes(); #>
   <# var sConn = "Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Server=servername\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDwh_meta;Integrated Security=SSPI;"; #>
  <# var sSQL = "SELECT * FROM SsisPackages"; #>
  <# DataTable tblPackages = ExternalDataAccess.GetDataTable(sConn,sSQL); #>
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">

    <# foreach (DataRow row in tblPackages.Rows){ #>
   <Connections>
    <AdoNetConnection Name="Source"
                      ConnectionString="Data Source=<#=row["Source"]#>;Initial Catalog=<#=row["DbName"]#>;Integrated Security=True;"
                      Provider="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                      CreateInProject="true"
                      />
    <AdoNetConnection Name="Destination"
                     ConnectionString="Data Source=<#=row["Destination"]#>;Initial Catalog=<#=row["DbName"]#>;Integrated Security=True;"
                     Provider="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                     CreateInProject="true"
                     />
                     <AdoNetConnection Name="Destination_Updates"
                     ConnectionString="Data Source=<#=row["Destination"]#>;Initial Catalog=<#=row["DbName"]#>_Update;Integrated Security=True;"
                     Provider="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                     CreateInProject="true"
                     />
                      <AdoNetConnection Name="Destination_Deletes"
                     ConnectionString="Data Source=<#=row["Destination"]#>;Initial Catalog=<#=row["DbName"]#>_Delete;Integrated Security=True;"
                     Provider="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                     CreateInProject="true"
                     />
                     
  </Connections>
  <Packages>
    <Package Name="<#=row["PackageName"]#>" ConstraintMode="Linear" ProtectionLevel="EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey">
      <Variables>
        <Variable Name="CDC_State" DataType="String"></Variable>
      </Variables>
      <Tasks>
        <CustomTask Name="CDC Get processing range"
                    CreationName="Attunity.SqlServer.CDCControlTask.CdcControlTask, Attunity.SqlServer.CDCControlTask, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa342389a732e31c">
          <ObjectData>
            <![CDATA[<CDCControlTask
          Connection="Source"
          TaskOperation="GetProcessingRange"
          OperationParameter=""
          StateConnection="Destination"
          StateVariable="User::CDC_State"
          AutomaticStatePersistence="True"
          StateName="CDC_State"
          StateTable="[dbo].[cdc_states]"
          CommandTimeout="30"
          ChangeDetectionRetryInterval="10"
          ChangeDetectionTimeout="60" />]]>
          </ObjectData>
        </CustomTask>
        <# foreach (var table in tables) { #>
        <Container Name="SEQ DepartmentGroup_<#=table.Name#>" ConstraintMode="Linear">         
          
          <Tasks>
            
          
               
            <Dataflow Name="DFT Incremental load_<#=table.Name#>">
              <Transformations>
               
                <CustomComponent Name="CDCSource"
                    ComponentClassId="{874F7595-FB5F-40FF-96AF-FBFF8250E3EF}"
                    ComponentTypeName="Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSrc.CdcSourceComponent, Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSrc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa342389a732e31c"
                    ContactInfo="Attunity Ltd.; All Rights Reserved; http://www.attunity.com;"
                    UsesDispositions="true"
                    Version="2"
                    ValidateExternalMetadata="false">
                  <Annotations>
                    <Annotation AnnotationType="Description">Specifies the content of the metadata columns and the rows returned. Modes starting with ‘All’ return all changes and modes starting with ‘Net’ return net changes.</Annotation>
                  </Annotations>
                  <Connections>
                    <Connection Name="Connection" ConnectionName="Source" />
                  </Connections>
                  <CustomProperties>
                    <CustomProperty Name="StateVariable"
                                    DataType="String"
                                    TypeConverter="Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSrc.PackageVariablesTypeConverter, Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSrc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa342389a732e31c"
                                    SupportsExpression="true"
                                    Description="An SSIS string package variable to store the CDC state of the current CDC state."
                                >User::CDC_State</CustomProperty>
                    <CustomProperty Name="CDCProcessingMode"
                                    DataType="Int32"
                                    TypeConverter="Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSrc.CdcProcessingMode, Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSrc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa342389a732e31c"
                                    SupportsExpression="true"
                                    Description="Specifies the content of the metadata columns and the rows returned. Modes starting with ‘All’ return all changes and modes starting with ‘Net’ return net changes."
                                >2</CustomProperty>
                    <CustomProperty Name="CaptureInstance"
                                    DataType="String"
                                    SupportsExpression="true"
                                    Description="The name of the CDC capture instance. By default the capture instance name is in the form of &quot;&lt;owner&gt;_&lt;table&gt;&quot;. The actual table that stores the changes is the CDC table named &quot;cdc&quot;.&quot;&lt;capture-instance&gt;_CT&quot;"
                                ><![CDATA[dbo_<#=table.Name#>]]></CustomProperty>
                    <CustomProperty Name="CommandTimeout"
                                    DataType="Int32"
                                    SupportsExpression="true"
                                    Description="The number of seconds before a command times out.  A value of 0 indicates an infinite time out."
                                >30</CustomProperty>
                    <CustomProperty Name="ReprocessingIndication"
                                    DataType="Boolean"
                                    SupportsExpression="true"
                                    Description="If true, a special output column called ‘__$reprocessing ’ is added. This output column is true for each data row during the initial processing range, or when the previous CDC run&#xA;was stopped without finishing. The default value is false (the __$reprocessing output column is not generated). This special output column allows the SSIS developer to handle consistency errors differently when working on the Initial Processing Range or the previous CDC run was stopped."
                                >false</CustomProperty>
                  </CustomProperties>
                  <OutputPaths>
                    <OutputPath Name="Output" >
                      <OutputColumns>
                        <OutputColumn Name="__$start_lsn" ExternalMetadataColumnName="__$start_lsn" DataType="Binary" Length="10" ErrorRowDisposition="FailComponent" TruncationRowDisposition="FailComponent"/>
                        <OutputColumn Name="__$operation" ExternalMetadataColumnName="__$operation" DataType="Int32" ErrorRowDisposition="FailComponent" TruncationRowDisposition="FailComponent" />
                        <OutputColumn Name="__$update_mask" ExternalMetadataColumnName="__$update_mask" DataType="Binary" Length="128" ErrorRowDisposition="FailComponent" TruncationRowDisposition="FailComponent"/>
                        <# foreach (var column in table.Columns) { #>
                          <# if (column.DataType == System.Data.DbType.AnsiString) { #>
                             <OutputColumn Name="<#=column.Name#>" ExternalMetadataColumnName="<#=column.Name#>" DataType="String" Length="<#=column.Length#>" ErrorRowDisposition="FailComponent" TruncationRowDisposition="FailComponent" />
                             <# } else { #>
                          
                                     <OutputColumn Name="<#=column.Name#>" ExternalMetadataColumnName="<#=column.Name#>" DataType="<#=column.DataType#>" Length="<#=column.Length#>" ErrorRowDisposition="FailComponent" TruncationRowDisposition="FailComponent" />
                         <# } #>
                        <# } #>
                      </OutputColumns>
                      <ExternalColumns>
                        <ExternalColumn Name="__$start_lsn" DataType="Binary" Length="10" />
                        <ExternalColumn Name="__$operation" DataType="Int32" />
                        <ExternalColumn Name="__$update_mask" DataType="Binary" Length="128" /> 
                        <# foreach (var column in table.Columns) { #>
                          <# if (column.DataType == System.Data.DbType.AnsiString) { #>
                             <ExternalColumn Name="<#=column.Name#>" DataType="String" Length="<#=column.Length#>" />
                             <# } else { #>
                        <ExternalColumn Name="<#=column.Name#>" DataType="<#=column.DataType#>" Length="<#=column.Length#>" />
                           <# } #>
                       <# } #>
                      </ExternalColumns>
                    </OutputPath>
                    <OutputPath Name="ErrorOutput" IsErrorOutput="true">
                      <OutputColumns>
                        <OutputColumn Name="__$start_lsn" DataType="Binary" Length="10"  />
                        <OutputColumn Name="__$operation" DataType="Int32"  />
                        <OutputColumn Name="__$update_mask" DataType="Binary" Length="128" />
                         <# foreach (var column in table.Columns) { #>
                           <# if (column.DataType == System.Data.DbType.AnsiString) { #>
                             <OutputColumn Name="<#=column.Name#>" DataType="String" Length="<#=column.Length#>" />
                            <# } else { #>
                        <OutputColumn Name="<#=column.Name#>" DataType="<#=column.DataType#>" Length="<#=column.Length#>" />
                        <# } #>
                       <# } #>
                      </OutputColumns>
                    </OutputPath>
                  </OutputPaths>
                </CustomComponent>


                <CustomComponent Name="CDCSplitter"
                    ComponentClassId="{874F7595-FB5F-40FF-96AF-FBFF8250E3EF}"
                    ComponentTypeName="Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit.CdcSplitterComponent, Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa342389a732e31c"
                    ContactInfo="Attunity Ltd.; All Rights Reserved; http://www.attunity.com;"
                    UsesDispositions="true"
                    Version="1"
                    ValidateExternalMetadata="false">
                  <Annotations>
                    <Annotation AnnotationType="Description">Directs a stream of net change records into different outputs based on the type of the change (Insert, Delete and Update). This allows specific handling for different types of change records.</Annotation>
                  </Annotations>
                  <InputPaths>
                    <InputPath Identifier="Input" OutputPathName="CDCSource.Output" >
                      <InputColumns>
                        <InputColumn SourceColumn="__$start_lsn"  />
                        <InputColumn SourceColumn="__$operation"   />
                        <InputColumn SourceColumn="__$update_mask" />
                         <# foreach (var column in table.Columns) { #>
                        <InputColumn SourceColumn="<#=column.Name#>"  />
                       <# } #>
                      </InputColumns>
                    </InputPath>
                  </InputPaths>
                  <OutputPaths>
                    <OutputPath Name="InsertOutput" SynchronousInput="Input" ExclusionGroup="1">
                      <Annotations>
                        <Annotation AnnotationType="Description">Output type - Insert.</Annotation>
                      </Annotations>
                      <CustomProperties>
                        <CustomProperty Name="OutputType" DataType="Int32"
                                        TypeConverter="Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit.OutputType, Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa342389a732e31c"
                                    >0</CustomProperty>
                      </CustomProperties>
                      <OutputColumns>
                      
                      </OutputColumns>
                      <ExternalColumns /> 
                    </OutputPath>

                    <OutputPath Name="UpdateOutput" SynchronousInput="Input" ExclusionGroup="1">
                      <Annotations>
                        <Annotation AnnotationType="Description">Output type - Update.</Annotation>
                      </Annotations>
                      <CustomProperties>
                        <CustomProperty Name="OutputType" DataType="Int32"
                                        TypeConverter="Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit.OutputType, Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa342389a732e31c"
                                    >1</CustomProperty>
                      </CustomProperties>
                       <OutputColumns>
                       
                      </OutputColumns>
                    </OutputPath>

                    <OutputPath Name="DeleteOutput" SynchronousInput="Input" ExclusionGroup="1">
                      <Annotations>
                        <Annotation AnnotationType="Description">Output type - Delete.</Annotation>
                      </Annotations>
                      <CustomProperties>
                        <CustomProperty Name="OutputType" DataType="Int32"
                                        TypeConverter="Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit.OutputType, Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa342389a732e31c"
                                    >2</CustomProperty>
                      </CustomProperties>
                        <OutputColumns>
                      
                      </OutputColumns>
                    </OutputPath>

                    <OutputPath Name="ErrorOutput" IsErrorOutput="true"  SynchronousInput="Input" ExclusionGroup="1">
                      <Annotations>
                        <Annotation AnnotationType="Description">Output type - Error.</Annotation>
                      </Annotations>
                      <CustomProperties>
                        <CustomProperty Name="OutputType" DataType="Int32"
                                        TypeConverter="Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit.OutputType, Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa342389a732e31c"
                                    >3</CustomProperty>
                      </CustomProperties>
                       <OutputColumns>
                      
                      </OutputColumns>
                      <ExternalColumns />
                    </OutputPath>

                  </OutputPaths>


                </CustomComponent>


                <AdoNetDestination Name="ADO_DST Destination" ConnectionName="Destination">
                  <InputPath OutputPathName="CDCSplitter.InsertOutput" />
                  <ExternalTableOutput Table="[dbo].<#=table.Name#>" />
                </AdoNetDestination>
                <AdoNetDestination Name="ADO_DST Staging UPDATES" ConnectionName="Destination_Updates">
                  <InputPath OutputPathName="CDCSplitter.UpdateOutput" />
                  <ExternalTableOutput Table="[dbo].[<#=table.Name#>]" />
                </AdoNetDestination>
                <AdoNetDestination Name="ADO_DST Staging DELETES" ConnectionName="Destination_Deletes">
                  <InputPath OutputPathName="CDCSplitter.DeleteOutput" />
                  <ExternalTableOutput Table="[dbo].[<#=table.Name#>]" />
                </AdoNetDestination>

              </Transformations>
            </Dataflow>
   
   

            <ExecuteSQL BypassPrepare="false" Name="SQL Handle updates in batch_<#=table.Name#>" ConnectionName="Destination_Updates" >
              <# string upd ="Update Dest Set ";
                   foreach (var colex in table.Columns.Where(column => !table.Keys[0].Columns.Select(keyColumn => keyColumn.Column).Contains(column))) {
      upd = upd + "Dest." + colex + " = Upd." + colex + ",";
    }
             
            var updc = upd.Substring(0,upd.Length-1) + " From " + table.SchemaQualifiedName + " Dest Join [" + row["DbNameUpdate"] + "].[" + table.Name + "] Upd On Upd." + table.Keys[0].Columns[0].Column + " = Dest." + table.Keys[0].Columns[0].Column;#>
          
              <DirectInput>
               <#=updc#>
              </DirectInput>
            </ExecuteSQL>
       
            <ExecuteSQL BypassPrepare="false" Name="SQL Handle deletes in batch_<#=table.Name#>" ConnectionName="Destination_Deletes">
            
              
              <# string del="DELETE FROM ["+ table.Name +"] WHERE ["+table.Keys[0].Columns[0].Column +"] IN ( SELECT ["+ table.Keys[0].Columns[0].Column +"] FROM [" + row["DbNameDelete"] + "].["+ table.Name +"])"; #>
              <DirectInput>
              <#=del#>
              </DirectInput>
            </ExecuteSQL>


            <ExecuteSQL BypassPrepare="false" Name="SQL Drop staging tables Update_<#=table.Name#>" ConnectionName="Destination_Updates">
              
              
                 <# string Drop_upd="TRUNCATE TABLE ["+ table.Name +"]"; #>
              <DirectInput>
             
              <#=Drop_upd#>
              </DirectInput>
            </ExecuteSQL>
            
             <ExecuteSQL BypassPrepare="false" Name="SQL Drop staging tables Delete_<#=table.Name#>" ConnectionName="Destination_Deletes">
              
               <# string Drop_del="TRUNCATE TABLE ["+ table.Name +"]"; #>
                 
              <DirectInput>
             
             <#=Drop_del#>
              </DirectInput>
            </ExecuteSQL>

 
            <!--Close Container-->
          </Tasks>
            
        </Container>
<# } #>
        <CustomTask Name="CDC Mark processed range"
                    CreationName="Attunity.SqlServer.CDCControlTask.CdcControlTask, Attunity.SqlServer.CDCControlTask, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa342389a732e31c">
          <ObjectData>
            <![CDATA[<CDCControlTask
          Connection="Source"
          TaskOperation="MarkProcessedRange"
          OperationParameter=""
          StateConnection="Destination"
          StateVariable="User::CDC_State"
          AutomaticStatePersistence="True"
          StateName="CDC_State"
          StateTable="[dbo].[cdc_states]"
          CommandTimeout="30"
          ChangeDetectionRetryInterval="10"
          ChangeDetectionTimeout="60" />]]>
          </ObjectData>

        </CustomTask>

      </Tasks>
    </Package>
  </Packages>
      <# } #>
</Biml>
```

I am working on a SSIS project using BIML. The code was working perfectly but immediatley Biml validator showing error

Validating BIML Error 0 : BimlScript code produced an exception: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException in :line 0
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item in :line 0
at Varigence.Utility.TextTemplating.GeneratedTextTransformation5b7174f5b7ed4045af6ad5d04aa325a2+<>c__DisplayClass3.<TransformText>b__0 in CDC_Final.biml:line 255
at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext in :line 0
at BimlScriptCode in CDC_Final.biml:line 255. Exception type: ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Parse. There were errors during compilation. See compiler output for more information.

Please help to resolve this error

Comment: Could you possibly post some of your BIML script?

Comment: @Sean Coetzee Hi, I couldn't post it here. The code was working fine suddenly it started breaking. My older projects with some of the similar elements also started breaking after that. I tried in a different machine similar result. Wondering the code was working and all of a sudden all the codes breaking.

Comment: Something had to have changed. If you're using the same version of BIDSHelper and the same code, then something in your metadata exposed a bug in your Biml code. If you can't post the code, there's really now way we can help you.

Comment: Its a long code which i cant paste it here.I can surely share the code If you suggest me How to do that here

Comment: @Sean Coetzee I have edited the Question

Comment: @Sean Coetzee thank you for your observation. Could you suggest a tweak if there is no primary key

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is that not all the tables in your database have keys defined on them. So when the BIML compiler gets here:

```
foreach (var colex in 
   table.Columns.Where(column => !table.Keys[0].Columns.
         Select(keyColumn => keyColumn.Column).Contains(column))) {
```

it fails because `table.Keys` is empty. I have put an if statement around both `ExecuteSQL` blocks, i.e. the destination update and delete and the error goes away. Not sure what the logic should be in the case where the table doesn't have a key, or perhaps the problem is that all tables should have keys.

Comment: Thank you for the observation. In my case few tables don't have primary key, but first column is always unique. Any Idea to get around this problem without tweaking the schema to add a primary key?

Comment: You could use `table.Columns` if the `table.Keys` collection is empty and just take the first one to build your update and delete statements.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.I have 100 databases each having 400 tables. What will be the best approach , combining 100 package into one or 100 separate packages for incremental load?

Comment: With that many objects I would consider using dynamic SQL. Rather than trying to create a SSIS package with a specific flow for each.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in either your static biml or your bimlscript, you've gotten off with your tag count. It could be BIML tags, like `</Task>` or it might be C# tags like `}`

What you're seeing is basically the Biml compiler breaking as it parses the content.

Comment: I tried a different project with similar code which was working before. I observe that too stopped working throwing the same error. To confirm the same code was working before without any validation. It suddenly started throwing this error